# Chrome closed itself immediately after filling the form in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am working with selenium right now the below code works fine but after filling the form my chrome browser closes itself immediately. How do I prevent this from happening. I don't want the browser to close itself.

The code is below

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

time.sleep(5)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")

# selcting states
state_select = driver.find_element(By.ID,'State')
drp1 = Select(state_select)

drp1.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')


# selecting district
district_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="State"]')
drp2 = Select(district_select)

drp2.select_by_index(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium always automatically quits after a code is finished running. You can add a `time.sleep()` to keep it open

```py
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")

# selcting states
state_select = driver.find_element(By.ID,'State')
drp1 = Select(state_select)

drp1.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')


# selecting district
district_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="State"]')
drp2 = Select(district_select)

drp2.select_by_index(10)
time.sleep(30)
```

You can also do this by adding 'detach' option, as following:

```py
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")

# selcting states
state_select = driver.find_element(By.ID,'State')
drp1 = Select(state_select)

drp1.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')


# selecting district
district_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="State"]')
drp2 = Select(district_select)

drp2.select_by_index(10)
```